# Probleme with id increment

Tags: sql, insert, increment

when i do this request i have an error

```
INSERT INTO FR_METIERPUBLI(
D_NIDMTR,
D_NIDPUBLI
)
VALUES (
'SELECT MAX( D_NIDMTR ) FROM FR_METIERPUBLI + 1', 1000
```

i want to increment my id

Comment: Drop the single quotes. And tell us the SQL database you are using - MySQL? SQL server? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: You should never assign a primary key like this, especially if you database can be accessed by several clients at once, because this can leed to duplicate IDs. Most DB systems provide sequences or auto-incrementing fields which you should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try

```
INSERT INTO FR_METIERPUBLI(
D_NIDMTR,
D_NIDPUBLI)
SELECT MAX( D_NIDMTR ) +1, 1000 FROM FR_METIERPUBLI
```

However..**be very careful with this**..if 2 operations do this at the same time you will get a duplicate

you could do (on SQL Server at least) wrap it in a transaction and specify these locks

```
 INSERT INTO FR_METIERPUBLI(
    D_NIDMTR,
    D_NIDPUBLI)
    SELECT MAX( D_NIDMTR ) +1, 1000 FROM FR_METIERPUBLI with (UPDLOCK, HOLDLOCK)
```

Why don't you use a sequence or identity?

Comment: @Mercer, pay attention to this part especially:
Why don't you use a sequence or identity?

Comment: Depends onteh database you are using. This is database specific stuff, but most databases hav ea way to automatically increment an id field of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

without knowing the database, this is just a guess, but try this:

```
INSERT INTO FR_METIERPUBLI
        (D_NIDMTR,D_NIDPUBLI)
    SELECT 
        MAX( D_NIDMTR )+ 1, 1000
        FROM FR_METIERPUBLI
```

for SQL Server, try protecting against no rows existing by using this:

```
INSERT INTO FR_METIERPUBLI
        (D_NIDMTR,D_NIDPUBLI)
    SELECT 
        ISNULL(MAX(D_NIDMTR),0)+ 1, 1000
        FROM FR_METIERPUBLI
```